# Comma vs space in SVG polygon

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I noticed that Adobe illustrator will output something like this as an SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 521.92 138"><defs><style>.a{fill:#0e0e0e;}.b{fill:#535353;}</style></defs><title>macys_john</title>

<path class="a" d="M319.2,48.7a42.9,42.9,0,1,0,0,31.6v24.4h3.1V23.6h-3.1V48.7Zm-11.7,44a39.83,39.83,0,1,1,11.7-28.2A40.26,40.26,0,0,1,307.5,92.7Z"/>

<path class="a" d="M200.2,21.5c-12.2,0-20.3,5.6-25.1,12.3a37.57,37.57,0,0,0-4.7,9.1,29.89,29.89,0,0,0-5.2-10.4c-4.7-6.2-12.7-11-24.8-11s-20.3,5.6-25.1,12.3a40.48,40.48,0,0,0-3.6,6.3V23.6h-3.1v81.2h3.1V53.4a33.76,33.76,0,0,1,6.1-17.8c4.4-6.1,11.4-11,22.6-11s18.1,4.4,22.3,9.8a28.9,28.9,0,0,1,5.7,16.8v53.9h3.1V52.3a33.39,33.39,0,0,1,6-16.6c4.4-6.1,11.4-11,22.6-11s18.1,4.4,22.3,9.8a28.9,28.9,0,0,1,5.7,16.8v53.9h3.1V51.3a31.4,31.4,0,0,0-6.4-18.7C220.3,26.3,212.3,21.4,200.2,21.5Z"/>

<polygon class="a" points="476.4 23.4 473 23.4 439.7 100.6 408.3 23.4 405 23.4 438 104.6 423.6 138 427 138 476.4 23.4"/>

<path class="a" d="M518.6,70.6c-3.3-4.5-9.3-7.8-20.3-10.7-9.1-2.4-13.6-6.1-16-9.4a12,12,0,0,1-2.6-7.1V43h0V41.9a19.9,19.9,0,0,1,2.7-10.1c2.4-3.8,6.7-7.2,15.6-7.3,9.4,0,13.8,3.6,16.3,7.5a18.22,18.22,0,0,1,2.6,9.5v0.3L520,42V41.5a21.87,21.87,0,0,0-3.1-11.1c-2.9-4.7-8.7-9-18.9-9-9.7,0-15.4,4.1-18.3,8.7a22.79,22.79,0,0,0-3.2,11.8v1.4a15.17,15.17,0,0,0,3.2,9c2.8,3.9,8.1,8,17.7,10.5,10.8,2.9,16.1,6,18.6,9.6s2.9,7.9,2.8,14a17,17,0,0,1-6,12.5,22.32,22.32,0,0,1-15,5.6,23,23,0,0,1-14.3-5.1c-4.1-3.4-6.9-8.6-6.9-16h-3.1c0,8.2,3.3,14.4,8.1,18.4a25.27,25.27,0,0,0,16.3,5.8c13.4,0,24-9.9,24-21.1C522,80.4,521.9,75.2,518.6,70.6Z"/>

<polygon class="b" points="56.6 52.5 45.8 19.3 35 52.5 0 52.5 28.3 73.1 17.5 106.3 45.8 85.8 74 106.3 63.2 73.1 91.5 52.5 56.6 52.5"/>

<polygon class="a" points="475.4 16.1 480.6 12.3 485.9 16.1 483.9 10 489.1 6.2 482.6 6.2 480.6 0 478.6 6.2 472.2 6.2 477.4 10 475.4 16.1"/>

<path class="a" d="M368.7,24.7a39.84,39.84,0,0,1,28.2,11.7,38.91,38.91,0,0,1,8.6,12.9h3.3a42.93,42.93,0,1,0-.1,30.8h-3.3A39.9,39.9,0,1,1,368.7,24.7Z"/></svg>
```

but I dont see where in the w3c spec how some of the coordinate points can be expressed with space and not a comma. My question specifically is

1. Where in the/a spec does it claim this is proper?
2. Is there a difference between a space and comma for a point in terms of compatibility with viewers/browsers etc...

Answer (score 5):

The grammar for polyline/polygon points attribute is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PointsBNF)

The grammar for paths d attribute is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF)

In either case they both basically say that at most one comma is allowed provided that on both the left and the right of the comma you have a number so 31, 3 is valid but M, 5, 7 is not.

Firefox adheres closely to the specification, some other UAs may be more lenient in allowing extraneous invalid commas where they should not but all UAs support commas where they are valid.

Comment: Thanks - does "comma-wsp:" mean comma or whitespace? which is what lets this still work 

<polygon class="a" points="475.4 16.1 480.6 12.3 485.9 16.1 483.9 10 489.1 6.2 482.6 6.2 480.6 0 478.6 6.2 472.2 6.2 477.4 10 475.4 16.1"/>

Comment: The BNF defines what comma-wsp means

Comment: @Quotient `comma-wsp` is defined as `(wsp+ comma? wsp*) | (comma wsp*)`.  Which translated means: "One or more whitespace chars, an optional comma, followed by zero or more whitespace chars; OR a comma follwed by zero or more whitespace chars".